# CSS: circle with background image when hovering over to hide text gets deformed

Tags: css, hover, background-image, geometry

I am trying to have a number of circles that have background images and texts side by side. And I want when hovering over the circles the opacity of the image to change and also the text to disappear. Also, I don't want the underline sign for links to be shown. But I have a number of problems.

Here is my CSS code:

```
.ccont {
display: inline-block;
margin: 10px;
}

.circle {
  position: relative;
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.circle:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://deepchains.com/images/team.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.circle__text {
  padding: 1px;
  background-color: none;
}

.circle:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.ccont:hover {
  font-size: 0;
}
```

and here is the HTML code:

```
<center>
<A href="http://www.url1.html" ><div class="ccont" style="font-weight: bold"><div class="circle">This is <br>Text1</div></div></A>
<A href="http://www.url2.html"><div class="ccont" style="font-weight: bold"><div class="circle">Text2</div></div></A>
</center>
```

Here are the issues:

1. At the beginning when the page loads I see that because of `a` I get underline links under the images as is shown here:

[image]

2. When I hover over the left image, the text disappears but also the circle gets deformed as is shown here:

[image]

3. Finally when I hover over the right image its text correctly disappears as is shown here:

[image]

So here are my questions:

1. I have been trying to use `text-decoration: none;` in different places but I always see the underline marks under the images as they have links. How can I remove them?
2. Why when hovering over the left image, the image gets deformed, but the right image does not get deformed? The only difference is that the left image text has a `<br>` in it.
3. How can I have different background images for the left and right circles?

**UPDATE:**

I applied @chriskirknielsen solution and I get this:

[image]

The two images are not aligned correctly. It seems that the underlines are aligned and as two image texts have different heights it pushes two images to different vertical locations. If we can remove the underlines maybe this can be resolved?

Comment: your code does not correspond to what is shown in the images (both images aren't perfect circles, but none of them changes its form when it's hovered)...

Comment: @Johannes which browser ? because am able to reprodue his issue using chrome and it's a bit strange as behavior ...

Comment: My code is exactly what I have and the images are exactly What I see. Did you try This code?

Comment: @TemaniAfif FIrefox Mac. I just put the whole code posted above into an SO snippet and got the described behaviour/look

Comment: Yes I am using Chrome.

Comment: well the issue is with `display: table-cell;` but cannot explain exactly why :)

Comment: it's something related with the algorithm of calculating the dimension of table that rely on the content, and when you make font-size:0 you change the content and i guess your a kind of bug ... am not pretty sure but i guess something like this

Comment: Don't use <center> tag and table cell, text-decoration must set on the <a> tag, here is the demo - https://jsfiddle.net/6dq2ngfz/ with simplified markup and css.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your sizing issue occurs because of `box-sizing`. Adding `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` at the start of your CSS fixes this issue because the padding from the text is taken into account when calculating the layout.

**EDIT:** OP's issue seems to be triggered by the font-size, so maybe just make the font transparent is the best idea?

```css
.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.ccont {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

.cclink {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.circle {
  position: relative;
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-size: 0 0;
  background-position: -9999px -9999px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-flex;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.circle:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: inherit;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.circle__text {
  padding: 1px;
  background-color: none;
}

.circle:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.ccont:hover {
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <a href="http://www.url1.html" class="cclink">
    <div class="ccont" style="font-weight: bold">
      <div class="circle" style="background-image: url(http://deepchains.com/images/team.png);">This is
        <br>Text1</div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.url2.html" class="cclink">
    <div class="ccont" style="font-weight: bold">
      <div class="circle" style="background-image: url(http://deepchains.com/images/team.png);">Text2</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

PS: Your HTML code is not very compliant to today's standards. The `<center>` tag is deprecated, and tags should be lowercase.

Comment: yes but why it doesn't get back to initial state when hover ends ? am sure it's something to do with display: table-cell;

Comment: I have no issues on Firefox, Chrome or Safari on Mac. Could you tell us more about the issue on your end?

Comment: I think your `.ccont:hover {
  color: transparent;
}` change from my `.ccont:hover {
  font-size: 0;
}`  resolved it. It doesn't seem we need `* { box-sizing: border-box; }`

Comment: ah yes you changed the font-size ! that's why :) .. the issue is with the font-size

Comment: The goal of my change was so that the hover didn't trigger a reflow and thus your circles would stay the same size.

Comment: Also, can you or anyone else address two other questions on my list?

Comment: yes we can find many fixes but the main question is "why ?" this happen ... it's more important than providing another way i guess

Comment: @chriskirknielsen Any idea how to remove the underline marks and also change the background image for each circle in the HTML code? Please answer those if you can to make your answer complete and I then can accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @TJ1 My answer has been updated with a solution for different background images inherited through your `.circle` element. Can you tell me if your underline issue still appears, and which browser you are using?

Comment: @chriskirknielsen I can change the background image using your solution but the underline issue is still there, the only difference is that the underline now is in the middle of the circle. Also, the two images are not aligned anymore.

Comment: @TJ1 Could you tell me which browser and OS you are using? I can't pinpoint why the underline shows up for you and not for me. Have you played with the `outline` property?

Comment: @chriskirknielsen I am using Chrome on Mac computer. I am using your exact code.

Comment: @chriskirknielsen I have updated the question and have shown what I see based on your solution.

Comment: You are running "my" code inside some larger codebase, no? The Stack Overflow snippet does not show those lines so some of your other code must be influencing this. Also the sizing of your circles is different but this should be fixed using `box-sizing: border-box;`.

Comment: The underlines were originally under the circles in my code, but using your code they have moved in the middle of the image. Yes, I have a main CSS and this is just an add-on CSS. How can I find what causes the underline, even if it comes from my main CSS?

Comment: That is because of my change to `display: inline-flex` for cleaner code, as `table-cell` is a bit hacky - the underline is put on the text baseline. You can use the Inspector in Chrome to find out where your CSS adds these underlines.

Comment: @chriskirknielsen is there a way to force this underlines out even though it may be caused by my main CSS? I cannot find what is causing them even when I look at the chrome inspector.

Comment: You can test with `text-underline: none !important;` (on the link - `.cclink` class I added - would be a good start, but also on the children elements as the value isn't inherited) to see if it is indeed caused by this property somewhere in your CSS, and debug your way up to the source of these underlines.